# Wiring for a ceiling fan. Do I create a switch or can I hard wire directly from a wall outlet?

Tags: electrical, wiring, fans

I'm in the process of remodeling my bathroom and will be putting a counter top high electrical outlet in a corner as linen storage. I plan to draw power to this new outlet from an outlet on the opposite side of the wall (bedroom). Here is my question. I am looking to install this 13" ceiling fan in my bathroom sort of tucked in the corner of the room just above the outlet I'll install on the wall.

[image]

Can I just wire a Romex directly from the new outlet and run it up into the ceiling? Or do have (or is it preferred) to use a double junction box and create a switch to power this fan. Meaning, the new outlet  will be paired with a on/off switch and my electrical outlet.

The fan is operated from a handheld remote so I don't think adding a switch will create any benefit like turning it on and off. But if it's required by code then, of course, I'll connect it to a switch.

Comment: How far away would this new "outlet" be from the lavatory and shower and/or tub? By outlet do you mean a duplex receptacle in the wall? The bathroom receptacles by code cannot be on the same circuit as receptacles in rooms other than a bathroom, in your case a bedroom. I think the fan could possibly be powered from the bedroom circuit.

Comment: does the fan have a lead, or are the wires inside the metal support rod?

Comment: The fan and Romex to it will be on the opposite side of the wall of the shower and sink. In other words, the fan will be on the south facing wall but and the shower and sink are on the north and north east facing walls.

Answer (score 5):

### Can’t power bathroom receps from non-bathroom circuits

A recep in a bathroom is only allowed to draw power from 2 kinds of circuits, and this is a very narrow definition:

- A.  Circuits which **only** power bathroom receptacles (in any number of bathrooms)
- B.  Circuits which **only** power recep or hardwired loads in *this* bathroom

Any circuit that powers anything in a non-bathroom is instantly disqualified.

Your bathroom may already violate this rule, and as such, may be **grandfathered**.  The rule with grandfathering is you’re not allowed to make the situation *worse*.  So you can draw off an existing bathroom recep, even if it already violates the rule... but you cannot add a new violation by drawing off a bedroom recep.

As long as you have a controlling means for the fan that you consider reasonable (are you OK with your partner calling an electrician to unwire it if the remote breaks?) then you are all set.  I for one would feel better having some sort of disconnecting means.

Comment: Well if I'm going to connect it myself why can't I disconnect it? I don't see what you're implying by asking if I'm okay with my partner calling an electrician. And are you saying a disconnecting means is defined as having the fan controlled by a switch? I'm fine with doing that if people here with more experience advise in favor of this approach.

Comment: @Adrien You're not required to have a disconnecting means for that, but you have to ask yourself what happens when the remote breaks with the fan running.  If you're traveling, who is home? Will they be ducky-doo with it running 24x7?  Or will they need to get some help getting it shut off?  (that'd be an electrician).